# Trying to understand string variables in Postfix configuration, is this what's happening?

Tags: postfix

So, I've jumped in head first into Postfix for the first time through Virtualmin / Webmin on Ubuntu 16.04.

In the main.cf file, there are entries like:

mydestination = localhost, localhost.$mydomain, $myhostname, $mydomain

I am making an assumption here, but I believe the reason we use the $variables is to maintain a proper configuration should any of those values change, thereby keeping the mail server on target.

would the above yield the following:

mydestination = localhost, localhost.mydomain.com, server1, server1.mydomain.com

And finally, how do I validate the values that should be inserted into those variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `postconf` command to see the default values (`postconf -d`) and current (custom) values of postfix variables   (`postconf -n`)

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html

> The general format of the main.cf file is as follows:
>
> Each logical line is in the form `parameter = value`.  Whitespace around the "=" is ignored, as is whitespace at the end of a logical line.
>
> ...
>
> A parameter value may refer to other parameters.
>
> The expressions "$name" and "${name}" are recursively replaced with the value of the named parameter. ... **An undefined parameter value is replaced with the empty value.**
>
> When the same parameter is defined multiple times, only the last instance is remembered.
>
> Otherwise, the order of main.cf parameter definitions does not matter.

Your assumption that

```
mydestination = localhost, localhost.$mydomain, $myhostname, $mydomain
```

would yield the following:

```
 mydestination = localhost, localhost.mydomain.com, server1, server1.mydomain.com
```

Is only true when either somewhere in your configuration file those parameters have been specifically set or when server1.mydomain.com is the actual hostname of your server. See the manual for [myhostname](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myhostname) and [mydomain](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydomain)